# How to make React-Recharts responsive for all kind of device particularly?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm using [React Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/) to show some chart data. I am using `ComposedResponsiveContainer` for my app component and the heights of it is set to "100%" by default. But in my app, I can't see this.

I'm using Tailwind CSS and thought `className="h-full w-full"` would help, but it's not. I also changed its height and width to something like the image and its showing this error:

[image]

what can I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and width properties and set your container inside a grid-cols

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove height & width
2. Use ResponsiveContainer example:

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
  <AreaChart
    data={data}
    margin={{
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    }}
  >
  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip />
  <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```